# Change heading and include bold font in xtable to .pdf from RMarkdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, xtable

I am a beginner with RMarkdown and LaTex, although enjoying creating reports in R! I have picked up some code to create the exact .pdf report I am after, although having difficulty with some aesthetics.

My data is confidential but here is a replica of layout/ exact number of plots and tables, using inbuilt R datasets.

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: 14pt
geometry: margin=0.5in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---
<style>
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
  }
</style>

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```
\newpage
# Iris 
```{r fig.width=18, fig.height=7, echo=FALSE, comment=" "}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_classic()
```
<br>
<br>
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

t1 <- kable(subset(iris, Sepal.Length=="5.1", select = Petal.Length:Species),
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
t2 <- kable(subset(chickwts, feed=="horsebean", select = weight:feed), 
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
t3 <- kable(subset(mtcars, gear=="4", select = disp:wt), 
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, digits=2)

cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t1,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t2,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t3,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
)) 
```
````

I wish to tidy up the following, but am unsure how to do so:

- Make the `Iris` heading on page 2 bold and centered, but keeping it as a heading in the table of contents.

  - Bold the headings in each of the three tables
  - Centre all the text in each table
  - Remove the big gap after `1.7, 0.5, setosa` in Table 1 and consequently, the other tables in that row.

Any help or links to specific documentation would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The answer provided below worked well except my data contains a percentage column, which RMarkdown and LaTeX does not seem to like. I have updated my code with some dummy data, that is very similar to my confidential data, in the hope this bug can be solved.

Thanks!

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: 14pt
geometry: margin=0.5in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---
<style>
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
  }
</style>

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```
\newpage

# Iris 

```{r fig.width=18, fig.height=7, echo=FALSE, comment=" "}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_classic()
```
<br>
<br>
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

# Create some dummy data
Data <- data.frame(Fruit = sample(c("Apple", "Orange"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                     Score = sample(1:10))
# Include percentage column
Data$Percentage <- (paste0(round(100 * Data$Score/100), "%"))

t1 <- kable({x <- subset(iris, Sepal.Length=="5.1", select = Petal.Length:Species);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t2 <- kable({x <- subset(chickwts, feed=="horsebean", select = weight:feed);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t3 <- kable({x <- subset(Data, Fruit=="Apple", select = Score:Percentage);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)

cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t1,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t2,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        t3,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
)) 
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your table related issues, you can use the following to get your desired layout. The bold headings are obtained by wrapping the column names in `\code{textbf}`. If you wish to have table headings that can adapt to HTML output, you will need additional logic (or you'll need to use a different table generating package). With this, you need to set `escape = TRUE` in the `kable` call.

Centering the content is as simple as using the `align` argument in the `kable` function.

```
t1 <- kable({x <- subset(iris, Sepal.Length=="5.1", select = Petal.Length:Species);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
```

Your section heading would appear correctly if you put a line of white space both above and below `# Iris`.

To get the section heading centered, you may want to search for tips on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

#### `pixiedust` version

for some reason I don't understand, I'm having to set the `tabcolsep` parameter in these tables. Inside the `minipage` environment, you will need to use `float = FALSE`.  But this seems to give a good approximation of what you want without editing the data source.

Where you are using percentages, you'll want to use `sprinkle(halign = "center", sanitize = TRUE)`

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: 14pt
geometry: margin=0.5in
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{amssymb} 
- \usepackage{arydshln} 
- \usepackage{caption} 
- \usepackage{graphicx} 
- \usepackage{hhline} 
- \usepackage{longtable} 
- \usepackage{multirow} 
- \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---
<style>
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
  }
</style>

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```
\newpage

# Iris 

```{r fig.width=18, fig.height=7, echo=FALSE, comment=" "}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_classic()
```
<br>
<br>
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
library(pixiedust)

t1 <- subset(iris, 
             Sepal.Length == "5.1", 
             select = Petal.Length:Species) %>%
  dust(float = FALSE) %>%
  sprinkle(tabcolsep = 10) %>%
  sprinkle(bold = TRUE,
           part = "head") %>%
  sprinkle(halign = "center") %>%
  medley_bw()

t2 <- subset(chickwts, feed=="horsebean", select = weight:feed) %>%
  dust(float = FALSE) %>%
  sprinkle(tabcolsep = 10) %>%
  sprinkle(bold = TRUE,
           part = "head") %>%
  sprinkle(halign = "center") %>%
  medley_bw()

t3 <- subset(mtcars, gear=="4", select = disp:wt) %>%
  dust(float = FALSE) %>%
  sprinkle(tabcolsep = 10) %>%
  sprinkle(bold = TRUE,
           part = "head") %>%
  sprinkle(halign = "center") %>%
  medley_bw()

cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        print(t1, asis = FALSE),
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        print(t2, asis = FALSE),
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering",
        print(t3, asis = FALSE),
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
)) 
```
````

Comment: Appreciate your response - this code worked perfectly on all my dataframes that did not contain percentages. However, when I ran this with data containing percentages, the .pdf document did not compile. Perhaps your suggestion above does not work when there is a % sign in a column? When I ran my code without your edits, the .pdf compiled although there is not bold text. Please see my updated post and thanks again for all your help.

Comment: It didn't work with percentages because I turned off escaping. An unescaped `%` is a comment character in LaTeX. It will work if you use two backslashes in front of the `%` (eg `15\\%`)

Comment: Thanks, I added in the two backslashes in my data.frame and this worked. Is there an alternate way however, rather than editing the data.frame directly?

Comment: `pixiedust` creates tables pretty nicely without directly editing the data. It's more verbose and not really obvious how to get the latex code in order to use it the way you are. I can work up an example when I get to work.

Comment: `pixiedust` example added.